# How to properly check http status code for HttpResponseMessage in C#?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, httpresponsemessage

complete novice at C# reporting in

Lets say I have the following code

```
HttpResponseMessage response = ...
```

How would I check if the status code for `response` is a 403?

The property `StatusCode` is an object - as opposed to an integer, So I am not quite sure what to do.

Comment: The `StatusCode` property is an `enum`.  With defined values: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either use the `HttpStatusCode` enum or cast the enum to an integer:

```
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
{
   ...
}

or

if ((int)response.StatusCode == 403)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: @AlanSTACK I would like to add that the first one is the preferred way: speaking names which self-document their meaning vs magic numbers. What does 403 even mean? Here it means "Forbidden" - so why not write it out then.

Comment: Agree 100%! @ckuri

Comment: What about the case of a status code that is not part of the enum?